# Отсутствуют иконки в контекстных меню Firefox в Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

Помню, что раньше можно было в Ubuntu в браузере Firefox как-то активировать отображение иконок расширений для контекстного меню браузера, но в сети мне не удалось найти как это сделать в Ubuntu 15.04 (Unity).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может кто знает? Уж сильно не привычно без всех тех иконок. Пример из Windows 10 + Firefox:

[image: Скриншот контекстного меню Firefox (Windows 10)]

Comment: а что возвращают команды `gconftool -g /desktop/gnome/interface/menus_have_icons` и `gconftool -g /desktop/gnome/interface/buttons_have_icons`?

Comment: Корректный вопрос тематики SU. Считаю, закрывать не стоит.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, спасибо за ваш ответ. Обе команды возвращают `false`. Я так понимаю, что нужно установить в `true`, но как это правильно сделать?

Comment: @Sergey, понятия не имею, поможет ли это хоть в чём-то, но изменить значение (в данном случае — булевское) можно той же командой с немного другими параметрами: `gconftool -s путь -t bool true`, где `путь` — тот же, что и при получении значения.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, прежде чем начну экспериментировать, подожду, может кто-то ещё отзовётся на мой вопрос.

Comment: @Sergey, да не переживайте, ничего не сломается. если эффекта изменения не дадут (даже после рестарта сессии), просто верните обратно значения `false`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, выполнил две команды: `gconftool -s /desktop/gnome/interface/menus_have_icons -t bool true` и
`gconftool -s /desktop/gnome/interface/buttons_have_icons -t bool true`, но в итоге возвращается `false`. Выполнял через `sudo`.

Comment: *Выполнял через sudo* — (здесь идёт несколько невнятных междометий)... «через sudo» — это от имени **другого** пользователя (по умолчанию — *root*-а). изменяйте параметры для **текущего** пользователя, для себя, а не для *root*-а.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29524/discussion-between-sergey-and-alexander-barakin).